# Find a basis for the kernel of the linear transformation $S : P_4 \to \Bbb R$ given by $S(p) = p(1) − p(0)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the kernel of the linear transformation $S : P_4 \to \Bbb R$ given by $S(p) = p(1) − p(0)$.

Note: $P_4$ is the set of polynomials with degree 4 or less and $\Bbb R$ is the real numbers.

I have gotten this far:

$$\ker(S) = \{p \in P_4 : p(1)-p(0) = 0\}$$

This implies that the kernal contains polynomials such that $p(1) = p(0)$. So I took a standard fourth degree polynomial:

$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$

and evaluated it at $1$ and $0$ giving me:

$$a+b+c+d=0$$

I am not sure if this is the correct approach or where to go from here.

Comment: Now write d = -a-b-c,  and substitute in your polynomial

Comment: So is ${ax^4,bx^3,cx^2,(-a-b-c)x,e}$ a basis for the kernel?

Comment: No... I'm going to write an answer, hang on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $d = -a-b-c$ as you pointed out, we have that $$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + (-a-b-c)x +e$$

Now, we can write this as $$a(x^4-x)+b(x^3-x)+c(x^2-x)+e\cdot 1,$$ so every polynomial in the kernel is a linear combination of $x^4-x$, $x^3-x$, $x^2-x$ and $1$. It's easy to check that these four polynomials are linearly independent, so they form a basis for the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Its much appreciated.